# Use code to disable player input unreal engine

Tags: c++, unreal-4

I have seen a lot of ways to use the node based visual scripts to stop player input; However, I have not seen a single example of how to disable the player input in visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable player input using the function:

`AActor::DisableInput(APlayerController* PlayerController)`

This should be called on the actor you wish to disable input for. You need to have a pointer to the current player controller, and pass this as the function's argument. You can easily get the first (and usually *only*, in single player game) player controller from the current world:

`UWorld::GetFirstPlayerController();`

Quick example, with `PlayerPawn` being a pointer to the AActor that you wish to disable input for:

```
APlayerController* PlayerController = GetWorld()->GetFirstPlayerController();
PlayerPawn->DisableInput(PlayerController);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation on PlayerInputComponent](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/APawn/SetupPlayerInputComponent/index.html)

It's been quite some time since I've used UE4 in a moderate-sized project, but what I would do first is:

1. Get `UInputComponent* Temporary =  PlayerInputComponent;`
2. Set `PlayerInputComponent = nullptr;` to block input
3. Later restore input by `PlayerInputComponent = Temporary;`

You might be able to use C++ standard move semantics with UE4, though I wouldn't guarantee it because usually UE4 does things in it's own weird but necessary way. What I posted above would be the first thing I'd do, so no guarantees if it works. Would be great if someone could confirm or deny.

**ALSO**: Please note that Visual Studio is not the only way to access/modify C++ code in UE4 environment. You can basically use any text editor to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Set (Pawn)->InputEnabled() to true or false. If you can find a blueprint node to do what you want, there's a good chance the code function is very similarly named.